# Jquery autocomplete on select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete and its working fine, now I want to store a variable in session from jQuery when following condition occurs.

When someone types any word jQuery shows suggestion dropdown, if someone select an item from that suggestion dropdown.

I want to capture above point and store a variable in session.

I searched Google, StackOverflow but find no relevant solution. My code for autocomplete is following:

```
  $(".autosearch-smart").autocomplete('Home/GetCompanyNames', {
    minChars: 1,
    width: 402,
    matchContains: "word",
    autoFill: true
});
```

and this is what I tried to do:

```
  $(".autosearch-smart").autocomplete('Home/GetCompanyNames', {
    minChars: 1,
    width: 402,
    matchContains: "word",
    autoFill: true,
    select: function (a, b) {
        alert("selected");
    }

});
```

**EDIT : Select event handler is also not working**

I am using asp.net MVC3 with C#. Please help me out and thanks in advance.

Comment: check your error console what it says...?

Comment: nothing showing in console @Anant

Comment: @smartboy What are the jquery libraries you used??

Comment: I posted some question regarding autocomplete.Can you check this and say what is wrong with that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860915/what-event-is-used-in-order-to-show-an-alert-message-on-selecting-a-value-in-the/36861040?noredirect=1#comment61292092_36861040

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to store the selected value in a variable sessions

you can get the value out of the selected item through following code:

```
  $(".autosearch-smart").autocomplete('Home/GetCompanyNames', {
minChars: 1,
width: 402,
matchContains: "word",
autoFill: true,
select: function (event, ui) {
    var label = ui.item.label;
    var value = ui.item.value;
   //store in session
  document.valueSelectedForAutocomplete = value 
}
});
```

the value and label are json objects that came from the server

Hope this helps

Comment: Select event is not working as i told you in my question and i tried it again but got no success

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to store in session using asp.net mvc3 then do the following

```
$(".autosearch-smart").autocomplete('Home/GetCompanyNames', {
    minChars: 1,
    width: 402,
    matchContains: "word",
    autoFill: true,
    select: function (event, ui) {   //must be cleared with function parameter
        //alert(ui.item.label);  //will show you the selected item

       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/Controller/Action1',  //whatever any url
          data: {label: ui.item.label},
          success: function(message) { if(message.data == true) ... else ... },
          dataType: 'json'
       });

    }

});
```

and controller

```
[HttpPost]
  public JsonResult Action1( string label ) {

     this.Session["AnyValue"] = label;

     return Json( new {
        data = true
     }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
  }
```

Comment: Don't think you need the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet setting as this is filtered as HTTPPOST

Comment: Is optional (JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)