# Trying to retrieve 'term' parameter in one of the callback functions within an autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, magento, client-side

I have the following javascript code - I want to use the 'term' $_GET variable within the onSelect() callback functions.

Can anyone explain how I do this? I have tried to use console.log within the callback but this doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#org_search_term, #org_search_postcode').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('rp/organisation/search', array('_secure' => true)) ?>',
    paramName:'term',
    minChars: 3,
    deferRequestBy: 500,
    dataType: 'json',
    onSearchStart: function(){
        $('#org_search_term, #org_search_postcode').addClass('loading');
    },
    onSearchComplete: function(){
        $('#org_search_term, #org_search_postcode').removeClass('loading');
    },
    onSearchError: function(){
        $('#org_search_term, #org_search_postcode').removeClass('loading');
    },
    onSelect: function(selected, data) {
      console.log(this); // this doesn't seem to work
    },
    transformResult: function (response) {

        var results = { suggestions:[] };

        if (!response.totalRecords)
            return false;

        $.each(response.items, function(i, item){
            results.suggestions.push({
                value: item.organisation_name+', '+item.street+', '+item.town+', '+item.county+', '+item.postcode+', '+item.country,
                data:  item.organisation_id,
                organisation_name: item.organisation_name
            });
        });

        // add the catch all result
        results.suggestions.push({
            value: '<?php echo $this->__('My org is not listed') ?>',
            data: null,
            organisation_name: null
        });

        return results;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [Jquery autocomplete on select event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722891/jquery-autocomplete-on-select-event)

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    var label = ui.item.label;
    var value = ui.item.value;
}
```