# How to search text from json and display in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am listing project name from json result and display in side bar. When click on side bar listed any of project name it shows the details of it. Now i have search box to search projects and display project details and get selected project name in side bar.

here is the search box code :

```
   <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" id="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
```

here is the result of json:

```
 "projects": [
{
"instances": null,
"name": "decodingideas",
"projectid": "decodingideas-147616",
"projectnumber": 334691107943,
"orgid": "",
"orgname": "",
"parentid": "",
"parenttype": ""
},
 {
"instances": null,
"name": "pupil-workers",
"projectid": "pupil-workers",
"projectnumber": 455648594684,
"orgid": "",
"orgname": "",
"parentid": "",
"parenttype": ""
}
```

Here i will be searching projectid, name or instance, etc.

here is the code used in html:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
  <div id="projectlist" class="sidebar-sticky">
    <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills">

      {{range .Projects}}
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">

          <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" 
  src="static/image/generic_gcp.png">
          {{.Name}}

          <div>
            <small>
            ProjectId: {{.ProjectID}}
          </small>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>
        {{end}}

    </ul>

 <!-- Might need this seperator
    <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items- 
 center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
      <span>Savings Reports</span>
    </h6>
  -->
  </div>
</nav>
   <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
  {{range .Projects}}

  <div id={{.ProjectID}} class="d-none justify-content-between flex-wrap 
 flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom ">
    <h1 class="h2">Project:{{.Name}}</h1>
```

How can list search and display project details and get selected in side bar of that project name.

Comment: do you mean you want auto complete or type someing search and display the result??

Comment: @לבנימלכה i need both

Comment: what data will you want to show in auto complete from json??

Comment: How do you threat search results? Pick only best one? Show a result list and then pick from it? Maybe you want to show all matching projects at once?

Comment: @לבנימלכה name and projectid, instance

Comment: @לבנימלכה show a result list and pick from it to display in detail

Comment: you can try https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp   and example https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

Comment: @Nirali how to do with local json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is auto complete from Jquery ui:

```js
  $( function() {
 var projects= [
{
"instances": null,
"name": "decodingideas",
"projectid": "decodingideas-147616",
"projectnumber": 334691107943,
"orgid": "",
"orgname": "",
"parentid": "",
"parenttype": ""
},
 {
"instances": null,
"name": "pupil-workers",
"projectid": "pupil-workers",
"projectnumber": 455648594684,
"orgid": "",
"orgname": "",
"parentid": "",
"parenttype": ""
}
];
    $( "#projects" ).autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
           response($.map(projects, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value.name+" "+ value.projectid,
                    value: value.projectid
                }
            }));
        
    }, 
      select: function(event, ui) {
           var res= $('#projects').val(ui.item.projectid);
           }
    });
  } );
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 SEarch: <input id="projects">
```

**If you want source with ajax:**

```
    var url="";//your url to json file
    source: function(request,response)  
    { 
      $.get(url, function(data)
      {         
        obj = JSON.parse(data);   //parse the data in JSON (if not already)
        response($.map(obj, function(value, key)
        {
         return {
                        label: value.name+" "+ value.projectid,
                        value: value.projectid
                    }
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i show result without declaring var projects from json. my json filename default.json?

Comment: you have to do it with ajax

Comment: How to load local json file

Comment: try to write in url your json file loction

Comment: how can i use this code $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/cache.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term},
        success: function(data) {
            var cat_data = $.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.label,
                    category: item.category,
                    desc: item.desc
                };
            });
            $("#searchfield").catcomplete({
                delay: 0,
                source: cat_data,
                minlength:0            });
  }
 });
});

Comment: This works fine but selected project is not displaying

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722891/jquery-autocomplete-on-select-event

Comment: acually I never did it before It my first time i did it **only** for you

Comment: $(function() { $.ajax({ url: "/path/to/cache.json", dataType: "json", data: {term: request.term}, success: function(data) { var cat_data = $.map(data, function(item) { return { label: item.label, category: item.category, desc: item.desc }; }); $("#searchfield").catcomplete({ delay: 0, source: cat_data, minlength:0 }); } }); }); how to use this code